# How to pass a parameter to an SQL script to change argument 2 of DATEADD() in VB.net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, dateadd

I am trying to send a parameter from a drop down box to an SQL server script that will change argument 2 of `DATEADD()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.Order_ID, Customers.First_Name, Orders.Order_Date, Payment_Details.Card_Name, Payment_Details.Card_Type, Payment_Details.Customer_ID
FROM            Orders INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON Orders.Customer_ID = Customers.Customer_ID INNER JOIN
                         Payment_Details ON Orders.Payment_ID = Payment_Details.Payment_ID
WHERE        (Orders.Order_Date < CONVERT(Varchar(20), DATEADD(d, CONVERT(dec, @DATE), { fn CURDATE() })));
```

And in turn this will populate a grid view with the results:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim OrderHistorySearch As New Allin1IDTableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter
        GridView1.DataSource = OrderHistorySearch.GetDataByOrderHistory(Me.DropDownList1.Text)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

However I am getting an error stating:

> Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime.

and

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

However, when working on the SQL Server wizard, the query works completely fine.

I tried converting the data type, but nothing seems to work.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Are you building that SQL statement in code or is that the SQL statement that works directly from sql-server?

Comment: What string are you passing to the DATE parameter?    And what is { fn CURDATE() } supposed to be?

Comment: The SQL Statement works directly from the sql-server.

Comment: The string being passed is Either 1,2,3,5,10,15. Depending in the option picked in the drop-down list. The CURDATE is current date the " {fn} " was added in automatically from the SQL server wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues, let me get the non-critical one out of the way first:

1. The second argument of `DATEADD()` should be an integer.

First, why not a decimal? Try subtracting half a day (or hour, minute, etc.) from the current date and SQL Server won't subtract 12 hours, it'll just round it down to 0 and return the current date. So no reason to accept non-integers; leaving the option open could only induce into errors.

Second, if you have declared the `@DATE` parameter as an integer type, there shouldn't be any need for `CONVERT()` at all - you just make sure your code feeds an integer to the SQL query. By the way, I'd call it something less misleading, such as `@NUMBER_OF_DAYS`.

2. `{ fn CURDATE() }` is an [ODBC function call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fasyf1c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

The SQL Server function to get the current date isn't `CURDATE()`, it is actually `GETDATE()`. The expression suggested by the wizard is meant to make the code more portable, allowing it to run on other SQL platforms that don't have `GETDATE()`, such as MySQL.

*However*, that function call has bigger problems, such as localisation. For example, on my system, which uses the European localisation, calling `DATEADD(day, 1, { fn CURDATE() })` bugs out and adds a *month* to today, because it erroneously treats it as a US date. But if I call `DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, { fn curdate() }))`, I get the correct result i.e. tomorrow.

What I suspect is happening is that in your localisation/configuration, `{ fn CURDATE()}` returns something that doesn't parse as a valid date at all. If portability isn't a concern, it would be best to replace the function call with a simple `GETDATE()`. In any case, try `SELECT`ing the following expressions on your server and seeing what the result is for each:

```
{ fn curdate() } 
CONVERT(DATE, { fn curdate() })
DATEADD(day, 1, { fn curdate() })
DATEADD(day, 1, CONVERT(DATE, { fn curdate() }))
GETDATE()
DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
```